# DateOnly in model C# class mapping to Date in SQL Server with EntityFrameworkCore

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework-core, dateonly

I have been scaffolded existing DB from SQL Server to my project with EntityFrameworkCore and it created models with

> public DateTime Birthday { get; set; }

Now I have to change DateTime to DateOnly
This exception is thrown when I'm trying to read Date (SQL Server) with model which has field

> public DateOnly Birthday { get; set; }

> Exception: The property is of type 'DateOnly' which is not supported by the
> current database provider. Either change the property CLR type, or
> ignore the property using the '[NotMapped]' attribute or by using
> 'EntityTypeBuilder.Ignore' in 'OnModelCreating'.

How can I use DateOnly struct from .NET 6.0 with SQL Server Date type?

Comment: Possibly related: [Support the new BCL DateOnly and TimeOnly structs for SQL Server](https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/issues/24507)